# Should we merge [wasm] and [WebAssembly]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

We have two separate tags for WebAssembly, [wasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wasm) and [webassembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webassembly). The former doesn't have a tag wiki, while the latter does. Should these tags be merged?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**tl;dr: Keep [webassembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webassembly), make [wasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wasm) a synonym of it.**

In the interest of keeping the fully spelt out version instead of the abbreviation, but allowing either to be used, I would favor making [wasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wasm) a synonym of [webassembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webassembly), thus making [webassembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webassembly) the canonical tag and causing anyone tagging a post with [wasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wasm) to automatically apply the [webassembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webassembly) tag.

Comment: It goes both ways. On one hand, we want the longer version [tag:webassembly], but many people prefer to name it with [tag:wasm].

Comment: @10Rep wouldn't making it a synonym accomplish that goal?  If they were synonyms, adding the [tag:wasm] tag to a question would automatically replace it with the [tag:webassembly] tag.  The same applies to searching: it'll automatically search for the canonical tag. See for example [searching for `[recycler-adapter]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[recycler-adapter]): it searches for the canonical tag.

Answer (score 7):

**Proposal**

1. Make [wasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wasm) a synonym of [webassembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webassembly)
2. <s>Transfer the wiki of the [webassembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webassembly) to [wasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wasm)</s><sup>0</sup>

**Reasoning**

1. [wasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wasm) is shorter, but [webassembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webassembly) has more than [1000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webassembly) questions, while [wasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wasm) has only [about 60](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wasm) attow. It makes sense to synonymize to the tag with the highest usage, and keep the utility of a well-know shortcut.
2. Since the [webassembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webassembly) has wiki info, and [wasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wasm) does not.

---

<sup>0</sup> Not necessary due to redirection to the [webassembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webassembly) wiki

Comment: part 2 of your proposal is not needed, because if wasm is a synonym, every time you enter it,either in a search or to tag a question, it will be changed automatically to webassemby. You'll never see a tag wiki for wasm.

Comment: @jps, you are right, the second point is a remnant of the first idea I had in mind (make [tag:wasm] main, and synonymize [tag:webassembly])...

Answer (score 5):

I'm in favor of merging the tags.  The [WebAssembly website](https://webassembly.org/) clearly cites *Wasm* as an abbreviation and a brief search couldn't find anything else that acronym/abbreviation presently means.

Unlike the other answer, I think we should use the longer *WebAssembly* name, keeping the shorter term as a synonym that redirects.

Short tags often lead to confusion as an acronym can mean multiple things -- perhaps not now, but in the future.  Longer tags are unambiguous and less likely to be misused.

Answer (score 2):

> Should these tags be merged?

Yes.

But since both terms are in circulation in web development circles, any future searches for the tag which is discarded should still deliver results for the tag which is kept: the two terms are exactly equivalent.

If that already happens automatically when two tags are merged, all the better.

Comment: Yes, that does. If the tags are merged and one uses the [tag:wasm] tag, then the system will automatically add the [tag:webassembly] tag and remove the [tag:wasm] tag.

Comment: I see. And then - to clarify - when I search for `wasm`, results are returned for `webassembly`?

Comment: @Rounin yes. just click on the tag `wasm` tag in the first comment and you'll see the result.

Comment: As a general user, I find it easier to glance through for a single term instead of remembering to check for two or more.

Comment: @Zach If there's more than one tag for a certain topic, you can create a custom filter that includes them all. That's easier than clciking on a dozen single tags on the watch list. For example you might be interested in `webassembly` or `blazor` or `blazor-webassembly` or `blazor-client-side` and create a filter "blazor/wasm" for it.